# how to merge config.yamls files on kubeconfig

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 yaml files with configuration and certs and everything from 2 different hyperscaler to use to access kubernetes clusters in each of them, so I wonder if I can add to my actual .kube/config file both of them , on my mac I have kind clusters and also in a VM so everything is fine I see them configured on my config file (one cluster from KIDN and another running on my VM) but idk if the merging this yamls can break this file and then have to get the config files again.

In short, I don't want to use `kubectl get ns -kubeconfig=configfile.yaml` every single time to access a context for a cluster, instead to put them in my config file

Any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export KUBECONFIG=/path/to/first/config:/path/to/second/config"`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/ has details.